# Converting Scala mutable arrays to a spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, arraybuffer

I have three mutable arrays defined as:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
var quartile_1 = ArrayBuffer[Double]()
var quartile_3 = ArrayBuffer[Double]()
var id = ArrayBuffer[String]()
```

quartile_1 and quartile_3 are information at id level and I am currently computing them as:

```
def func1(x: org.apache.spark.sql.Row) {
  val apQuantile = df_auth_for_qnt.where($"id" === x(0).toString).stat.approxQuantile("tran_amt", Array(0.25, 0.75), 0.001)
  quartile_1 += apQuantile(0)
  quartile_3 += apQuantile(1)
  id += x(0).toString()
}

val cardNumList = df_auth_for_qnt_gb.where($"tran_cnt" > 8).select("card_num_1").collect.foreach(func1)
```

Is there a better approach than appending them to mutable arrays? My goal is to have the quantile data, id available as a dataframe - so that I can do further joins.

Comment: there are three mutables and not four. I won't suggest you to go with mutables as mutables would not behave correctly in distributed system. Please add more information so that you get correct suggestions.

Comment: Would you recommend converting it to immutable array before creating the dataframe? If so, could you provide instructions on how to do it?

Comment: I told you to create more information and you have just repeated the same information that you already provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mutable structures like `ArrayBuffer` are evil, especially in parallelizable context. Here they can be avoided quite easily.

`func1` can return a tuple of `(String, Array[Double])`, where the first element corresponds to the id (former `id` buffer) and the second element is the quartiles returned from `approxQuantile`:

```
def func1(x: Row): (String, Array[Double]) = {
  val cardNum1 = x(0).toString
  val quartiles = df_auth_for_qnt.where($"id" === cardNum1).stat.approxQuantile("tran_amt", Array(0.25, 0.75), 0.001)
  (cardNum1, quartiles)
}
```

Now, using functional chaning we can obtain an immutable result structure.

As a DataFrame:

```
val resultDf = df_auth_for_qnt_gb.where($"tran_cnt" > 8).select("card_num_1").map(func1).toDF("id", "quartiles")
```

Or as a `Map[String, Array[Double]]` with same associations as in the tuples returned from `func1`:

```
val resultMap = df_auth_for_qnt_gb.where($"tran_cnt" > 8).select("card_num_1").map(func1).collect().toMap
```